# Delete multiple keys from array of Object

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

Let's say we have an array of object:

```
var obj = [{a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4, e: 5 },{a: 6, b: 7, c: 
8, d: 9, e: 0 }];
```

and we want to delete key c,e from both of the objects.

How can it be done? One of the methods I found is:

```
['c', 'e'].forEach(e => delete obj[e]); //for object
```

Is there any other way so we don't have to use double for loop.

Comment: `obj.map(({ c, e, ...rest }) => rest)` would create a new array of new objects with those keys removed.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you don't want to use a double for loop?  There should be very little difference for performance and it's the only option which is actually dynamic (in case `['c', 'e']` is actually not known at build, only runtime).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to do it is to use [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) together with [object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#object_destructuring):

```js
var obj = [
  { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4, e: 5 },
  { a: 6, b: 7, c: 8, d: 9, e: 0 },
];

var newObj = obj.map(({ c, e, ...rest }) => rest);
console.log(newObj)
```

This will create a new array with new objects which contain all of the other keys except for `c` and `e`.

Comment: Thank you so much....but could you please tell me why we used "...rest" for?

Comment: @SangamBasnet `({ c, e, ...rest })` will get `c` and `e` and store them in separate variables and all other properties will be stored in new object named `rest`. This is what the above syntax means

Comment: When you destructure an object (e.g. `const {c, e} = {a:1, c: 2, e: 3}`), you can choose the variables you want to pick out of the object. The `...` in there is called ["rest"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Rest_in_Object_Destructuring) and all other keys which were not explicitly picked out are stored in that object. The name of the variable can be anything, it doesn't have to be "rest".

Comment: The names are pretty intuitive actually: `...rest` simply collects all the "rest", i. e. the remaining properties of the destructured object - after `c` and `e` had been removed and places them together again in an object called `rest`.

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 options to resolve it:

1. By using [object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#object_destructuring):  `map(({ a,b,c,d,e }) => ({a,b,d})`
2. Enhance option 1 by using [using [Rest parameters]](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) `{ c, e, ...rest }`

- `Object destructuring` like below

  `const obj =  { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4, e: 5 } var {c, e} = obj; // c = 3, e = 5`
- With option 2, you will have `c,e` implicit name and `the remaining items` named `rest`. After that, you just need to get `rest` items.

**Option 1**

```js
var obj = 
[
  { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4, e: 5 },
  { a: 6, b: 7, c: 8, d: 9, e: 0 },
];
console.log(obj.map(({ a,b,c,d,e }) => ({a,b,d})));
```

**Option 2**

```js
var obj = 
[
  { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4, e: 5 },
  { a: 6, b: 7, c: 8, d: 9, e: 0 },
];
         
console.log(obj.map(({ c, e, ...rest }) => rest));
                           // ...rest: the same as `a,b,d`
```

Comment: There is an existing answer above which is same as this ...

Comment: Oh, I have more explanation with the same idea. Thanks @Codenewbie

Comment: @Sangam Basnet Does this answer your question? Let me know if you need any help.